# I see my Stack Overflow reputation score at the top bar instead of meta.stackexchange score when I switch from Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, meta

I suddenly faced the issue today. I was in Stack Overflow and I switched to Meta Stack Exchange by using the navigation at the top left dropdown. I noticed that I am seeing the reputation score of my Stack Overflow profile at the right side of the top bar.

I tested it multiple times and it did the same when I came to Meta Stack Exchange from Stack Overflow. But it doesn't happen when I switch from Stack Overflow to Code Review or Code Review to meta Stack Exchange.

[image: Top bar example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a child meta for Stack Overflow, not [Meta Stack Exchange proper](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), so it doesn't have separate reputation.

#### Related: [Operation 'Split, All The Metas!' Shall Commence On April 16, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014)

Comment: Oh. my bad. I see it now.

Comment: I see what you did there...

Comment: But why I see a different count for badges where the reputation point is same as stackoverflow? Isn't it something confusing?

Comment: @TareqMahmood You can earn badges on a child meta, just not rep.